# How to Set a Custom Garbage Collector Algorithm in Tomcat

Tags: java, garbage-collection, tomcat8

I want to set a custom garbage collector algorithm for my java application[war] which is running on top of tomcat. I am using java8 and the default garbage collector is parallelGC. I want to use G1GC or CMS GC instead of this.

```
java -XX:+UseG1GC -jar Application.java
```

A Jar application can be executed with the above command. 
But I want to know how we can configure this in tomcat/ with a war application?

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer, I will post it here for the community usage

When we need to set a custom GC for tomcat, we can pass the GC type as a parameter to the CATALINA_OPTS env variable.

```
export CATALINA_OPTS = "-XX:+UseG1GC"
```

You can set this env variable in setenv.sh file(tomcat/bin/setenv.sh) or jvmsettings.sh file(/etc/profile.d/jvmsettings.sh). Addition to the GC type you can pass other jvm parameters to the same command

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms4096M -Xmx7168M -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/settings/logs/gc.log"
```

After completing the configurations, restart the tomcat server. Then execute the following command to get the currently using GC type

```
jmap -heap <process_id>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that in the variables.conf file, where you can add it like this:

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
```

Comment: Hey Ankur, I added the variables.conf file with the above command to the tomcat/conf folder. But still, it's using the default JVM garbage collector.

Comment: After the changes, I executed the jmap -heap <process_id> command 
It returned this "using thread-local object allocation.Parallel GC with 4 thread(s)"

java -version: 1.8.0_131
Apache Tomcat Version 8.5.15

Any comments

Comment: Did you restart tomcat?

Comment: Yes restarted the tomcat server

Comment: Did you have the variables.conf already in tomcat or you added a new file? Probably there is some other file where you can try adding the java opt

Comment: Might wanna try setting the property in Catalina.sh or tomcat-startup.sh as java opts . Also check if there is any GC configured by default in the tomcat installation directories. conf directory generally contains configuration files..

Comment: Yes, Thanks Ankur
we can set the GC type to the CATALINA_OPTS variable. This worked for me.
I will add my whole configuration as an answer. It would useful for the community